# node.js express static images serving

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to include my static images at html page. So I do it like that:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And put all my images inside public under *'/images*' folder.
So then I call it like this:

```
<img src="images/image_1.jpg"/>
```

But my path when page loaded looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/product/images/image_1.jpg
```

Why did page url path *http://localhost:3000/product/* added before img src?

Comment: Did you try `<img src="/images/image_1.jpg"/>`, what you have is not an absolute path

Comment: omg, yes! I didnt noticed '/'

Answer (score 2):

If you're already at `http://localhost:3000/product` clicking a link with the href `images/image_1.jpg` takes you to `http://localhost:3000/product/images/image_1.jpg` as the URL is relative.

You probably wanted to use absolute paths instead

```
<img src="/images/image_1.jpg" />
```